# Stop a Python program until a user performs an action

Tags: python, gtk

My original program used `input`, like this:

```
n = input("Enter your favorite number: ")
# do stuff with number
```

Now, I have switched to a GTK GUI, but still want the accomplish the same thing. Now look at this very similar piece of code:

```
n = myWindow.getNumber()
# do stuff with number
```

Would it be possible to write a `getNumber()` method that only returns after the user presses a submit button in the window? (like the how the `input` function works) or is this my only option:

```
def callback(widget, event):
    n = myWindow.inputWidget.getValue()
    # do stuff with number

n = myWindow.getNumber(callback)
```

Update: I'm looking to do this without a gtk.Dialog, as I don't want a dialog popping up every time user input is required.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a modal dialog. I don't know GTK (or PyGTK) at all, but there appears to be an example [in the documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkdialog.html).

Comment: Thanks, but a modal dialog just prevents the user from interacting with any widgets outside of the dialog.

Comment: @Sam: as far as I know, the run method of gtk.Dialog does block the program and only returns when it gets a response (no need for a callback). Subclassing gtk.Dialog may be what you need.